# My raspberry pi’s text interface seems broken

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I just downloaded the NOOBS operating system for my raspberry pi-3. Everything seems to work except some texts are not displaying properly.
As you can see in the photo, they seem to be squares with 4 characters in it. By the way I set the language to Korean, does this have something to do with the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLSc3.jpg)

Comment: Maybe try here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

> By the way I set the language to Korean, does this have something to do with the problem?

Yes, very likely.

You could try installing the Korean font support for Raspbian. Try using this [link](http://www.raspberryconnect.com/raspbian-packages-list/item/64-raspbian-fonts).

Please see if you are able to install fonts and resolve the issue. Hope this helps! :)